# Script to kill -2 the PID and restart the process

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I'm facing problem while running a script 'restart.sh'. Its main objective is to kill a process by id, and restart the process again.

The process name has 'DND' as below

```
$ ps -ef | grep DND
root   18425     1 60 11:53 pts/0    00:40:34 java -jar DND_Retry.xml
```

NOTE : The PID will be changed every time the script is executed.

1 part of script given below:

```
  echo "Killing BND Process"

pids=$(pgrep -f BND)
for pid in "${pids}"; do
  if [[ $pid != $$ ]]; then
    kill -2 "$pid"
  fi
done

sleep 2

while true
do
shut1=`more /Data/v3/nohup_bnd.out |  grep  "has been shutdown" | wc -l`
        if [ $shut1 -eq 1 ]; then

    echo "process ended now restart"
```

The problem is: The script executes successfully first time but, when I execute again, it doesn't kill the process. However if I kill the process manually with Kill -9, and again execute the script it executes successfully and produce the desired result.

Is there anything I need to modify in above script/condition. I need to perform Kill -2.

Comment: So, how are you starting the script and how do you restart it? Is there any difference in how it appears in the output of `ps` depending on how it was started? (I can't see where your script would restart the program). Also, you have `BND` in the script, and `DND` in the sample `ps` output and in the text. Is that relevant or just a typo?

Comment: @ikkachu, It was a typo, it is BND..but the problem is, the script is not executing for the second time. Its not killing the PID 18425.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple PIDs running, then quoted variable `"${pids}"` causes a problem.
You need to remove the quotes.

**Example:**

```
$ pids=$(pgrep -f a_program_started_three_times)
$ for pid in "$pids"; do echo "pid is $pid"; done
pid is 563
564
565
$ for pid in $pids; do echo "pid is $pid"; done
pid is 563
pid is 564
pid is 565
```

**Optional:**

I would add an extra check to the for-loop.

```
pids=$(pgrep -f BND)
# if pid(s) were found, then...
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    # removed the quotes from "${pids}" here
    for pid in $pids; do
        if [[ $pid != $$ ]]; then
            kill -2 "$pid"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: still its not working.. when executing the script, its not killing the PID when we do kill -2 18425(PID).. Don't know whats going wrong.

Comment: Your background processes don't catch your SIGINT. Related: [Why do shells ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT in backgrounded processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106725/why-do-shells-ignore-sigint-and-sigquit-in-backgrounded-processes)

Comment: what should be the workaround on this.